# How to define a varialbe and refer to it later

Tags: vimrc, variables

I need to define variables who can hold number or strings. Those variables would be used later in the key mapping

for example

```
let bookMark=Lib7 //:echo boomMark do give out Lib7
nmap gb :<c-u>NERDTree<CR>:OpenBookMark 'bookmark'<Cr> //not working
nmap gb :<c-u>NERDTree<CR>:OpenBookMark bookmark<Cr> //not working
```

NB:

There is an typo here, it shall be `OpenBookmark`,

Comment: Are looking for `:execute`?

Comment: @LucHermitte yes but no. still not working, I have the error ` OpenBookMark :execute "echom bookmark" `. I think the variable is run time evalued

Comment: It's `:execute 'echom '.varname`

Comment: @LucHermitte still not working, `:OpenBookmark :execute 'echom' bookmark` is not give the input as `:OpenBookmark Lib7` but by simply typing ':execute 'echom' bookmark' in the command will return `Lib7`

Comment: ?? I though you knew that `:echom` isn't `:OpenBookmark`. If you wish to feed a variable name into `:OpenBookmark`, it becomes: `nnoremap gb :<c-u>NERDTree<CR>:exe 'OpenBookMark '.bookmark<Cr>`

Comment: @SLN please post your edit as an answer and accept it. This way future readers will know that your question has been answered and might be useful for them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Luc Hermitte's answer, the correct version are

`nnoremap gb :NERDTree<CR>:exe 'OpenBookmark '.bookmark<Cr>`
or

`nnoremap gb :NERDTree<CR>:exe "OpenBookmark" bookmark<Cr>`